# Binding css styles after a click in jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, css

Hi, I have a panel which has a scroll bar.

For this scroll bar I have a css class and I am binding it to a panel.

When I am doing my click event, which loads data into this panel, it is not showing a scroll bar.

Here is my code:

```
<div id='dvFlexScroll' class='flexcroll' style="overflow: scroll">
  <div style="height: auto;">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlContainer" runat="server">
      <div id="acc" class="pnlAcc" runat="server"></div>
    </asp:Panel>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just wanted to rebind this class `flexcroll` after my button click (which is done by a JSON call in ASP.net).

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: You don´t have to rebind CSS classes. Make sure the class does what it´s supposed to do and that you have applied it correctly. Is it really named "flexcroll" or should it be "flexscroll"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small hint for you, my friend;

write the following code on click in js:

```
$('div id to which u want to set new css').attr('class','new class name');
```

Comment: iam using Json calls for button clicks..,

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button-id").on('click',function(){
        $("#acc").addClass("flexcroll");
    });
});
```

Comment: $("#dvFlexScroll").addClass("flexcroll"); or $(".pnlAcc").addClass("flexcroll");

Comment: No , its not. I have given my panel class instead of div id, but i can see scroll bar when i debugg in browser

Comment: actually on which div you want add class ?

Comment: on <div id="acc" class="pnlAcc" runat="server"></div> i want to add id='dvFlexScroll'

Comment: <div id="acc" class="pnlAcc" runat="server"></div> has already ID attribute so why you want to add id='dvFlexScroll' again ?

Comment: i want that css to be bind to this <div id="acc" class="pnlAcc" runat="server">

Answer (score 0):

How about toggling the class after click. Say, like:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#divid").toggleClass("newclass");
});
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is this 'newClass'?? My div class or again other class?

Comment: add a newclass in your stylesheet.. css style to be binded in your div